# CrystalReports: System.ArgumentException: Resource 'DefaultAnimation.gif' cannot be found in class

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

I am trying to use the CrystalReports library from https://www.nuget.org/packages/CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms/ but I keep getting the following exception when I attempt to open a report in my winforms application.

I've searched online and a few people have talked about extracting and embedding the missing resource but how do I do that and where/how do I find it/get it?

```
  System.ArgumentException: Resource 'DefaultAnimation.gif' cannot be found in class 'UserInterface.CustomControls.MyReportViewer'.
       at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Type type, String resource)
       at CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportViewer.InitReportViewer()
       at CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportViewer..ctor()
       at UserInterface.CustomControls.MyReportViewer..ctor() in C:\Projects\UserInterface\CustomControls\MyReportViewer.cs:line 22
       at UserInterface.Controls.ReportingControl.FrmReportViewer.InitializeComponent() in C:\Projects\UserInterface\Controls\ReportingControl\FrmReportViewer.cs:line 60
       at UserInterface.Controls.ReportingControl.FrmReportViewer..ctor(Report reportToPrint) in C:\Projects\UserInterface\Controls\ReportingControl\FrmReportViewer.cs:line 247
       at UserInterface.Controls.ReportingControl.FrmReports.OnCustomCommandClicked(FormCommand commandClicked) in C:\Projects\UserInterface\Controls\ReportingControl\FrmReports.cs:line 310
       at  UserInterface.Controls.ReportingControl.FrmReports.gridEXReport_DoubleClick(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Projects\UserInterface\Controls\ReportingControl\FrmReports.cs:line 395
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnDoubleClick(EventArgs e)
       at Janus.Windows.GridEX.GridEX.OnDoubleClick(EventArgs e)
       at Janus.Windows.GridEX.GridEX.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem when I wanted to inherit the CrystalReportViewer.

I just added a image named 'DefaultAnimation.gif' in the project and set it's build action to Embedded Resource (right click on image - > properties)